# Phishing attack Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, phishing

We have a website published in Azure(Not Free). Which was working just fine but sometimes ago I just got "Phishing attack ahead Attackers on example.com might try to trick you to steal your information (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards) in chrome and Mozilla as well. can you guys tell me what's the issue? and why the message is coming?
Please note that the website is working locally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Google Chrome warns you if the site you're trying to visit is
>   suspected of phishing or malware, using Google’s Safe Browsing
>   technology.
>
> To protect you from dangerous websites, Google maintains a list of
>   websites that may put you at risk for malware or phishing.
>
> Google also analyzes website content and warns you if a site seems
>   dangerous.

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?hl=en

The following does not answer your questions, but it might be helpful: you can report an incorrect phishing warning to Google.

> Report Incorrect Phishing Warning: 
>   If you received a phishing warning but believe 
>   that this is actually a legitimate page, please 
>   complete the form below to report the error to Google.

https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Eykelen

Answer (score 0):

Many sites affected currently. Google probably detected a real phishing attack coming from one of the sites hosted on Azure (either a bot deployed one or the compromise of a legit site) and presumably got a bit heavy handed in the IP blocks.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass? How can we fix that?Obliviously we are not trying to steal anything from our users!

Comment: @AnkitSarkar See my answer for a fix.

Comment: @FrankVanEykelen Pierre is involved with a project that has over a thousand azure websites deployed. The support site for this project has been flooded with this today.

Comment: Thanks @DennisBurton. I was wondering because it wasn't exactly a trending topic in for example Twitter.